# I cannot add products into my cart View template

Tags: python, django

I am trying to add a product into my cart , but the product is not being able to add . AffProduct Model is the model where all the details of the product is being stored.
Whenever I click on the 'Add To Cart' button the pages are being rendered and all the css and html elements being also renderd , but the product is not being added.

Models.py

```
class AffProduct(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='foo')
    product_title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    uid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    specification = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sale_price = models.IntegerField()
    discount = models.IntegerField()
    img1 = models.ImageField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images/")
    img2 = models.ImageField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images/")
    promote_method = models.TextChoices
    terms_conditions = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    promote_method = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        choices=promote_choices,
        default='PPC'
    )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

This is my CartAdd View:

```
@login_required
@require_POST
def CartAdd(request, uid):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(AffProduct, uid=uid)
    form = CartAddProductForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        cart.add(product=product, quantity=cd['quantity'], update_quantity=cd['update'])
    return redirect('CartDetail')
```

This is my CartAddProductForm

```
from django import forms
from .models import Order

PRODUCT_QUANTITY_CHOICES = [(i, str(i)) for i in range(1, 21)]

class CartAddProductForm(forms.Form):
    quantity = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=PRODUCT_QUANTITY_CHOICES, coerce=int, label="quantity")
    update = forms.BooleanField(required=False, initial=False, widget=forms.HiddenInput)
```

The template where i have been trying to render

```
{% block content %} <h1>Your cart cargo </h1>
<table border="1px" class="table-cart">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Image</th>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Full Price</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody> {% for item in cart %} {% with product=item.product %}
    <tr>
        <td class="cart-img"><a href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}"> <img class="img-responsive"
                                                                            src="{{ product.img1.url }}"/> </a></td>
        <td>{{ product.product_title }}</td>
        <td>
            <form CartAdd action="{% url "
            " product.uid %}" method="post" class="add"> {{ item.update_quantity_form.quantity }} {{
            item.update_quantity_form.update }} {% csrf_token %} <input type="submit"
                                                                        value=" Refresh ">               </form>
        </td>
        <td><a CartRemove href="{% url "" product.uid %}"> Delete </a></td>
        <td class="num">{{ item.sale_price }}</td>
        <td class="num">{{ item.total_price }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endwith %} {% endfor %}
    <tr class="total">
        <td> Total</td>
        <td colspan="4"></td>
        <td class="num">{{ cart.get_total_price_after_discount|floatformat:"2" }}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<p> Apply coupon </p>
<form action="" class="add" method="post"> {% csrf_token %} {{ cupon_apply_form }}
    <input type="submit" value=" Refresh "></form>
<p class="text-right"><a class="btn btn-light"
                         href="{% url 'productdetails' %}"> Continue Shopping </a> <a class="btn" href="">
    Checkout </a></p> {% endblock %}
```

And below is the cart.py

```
from decimal import Decimal
from django.conf import settings
from affiliation.models import AffProduct
#from cupons.models import Cupon


class Cart(object):
    def __init__(self, request):
        # User cart initialization
        self.session = request.session
        #self.cupon_id = self.session.get('cupon_id')
        cart = self.session.get(settings.CART_SESSION_ID)
        if not cart:
            # Save the user's cart to the session
            cart = self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID] = {}
        self.cart = cart

    # Adding an item to the user's cart or updating the item quantity
    def add(self, product, quantity=1, update_quantity=False):
        product_id = str(product.uid)
        if product_id not in self.cart:
            self.cart[product_id] = {'quantity': 0,
                                     'price': str(product.sale_price)}
        if update_quantity:
            self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] = quantity
        else:
            self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] += quantity
        self.save()

    # Saving data to a session
    def save(self):
        self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID] = self.cart
        # We indicate that the session has been changed
        self.session.modified = True

    def remove(self, product):
        product_id = str(product.uid)
        if product_id in self.cart:
            del self.cart[product_id]
            self.save()

    # Iteration on loads
    def __iter__(self):
        product_ids = self.cart.keys()
        products = AffProduct.objects.filter(uid__in=product_ids)
        for product in products:
            self.cart[str(product.uid)]['product'] = product

        for item in self.cart.values():
            item['sale_price'] = Decimal(item['sale_price'])
            item['total_price'] = item['sale_price'] * item['quantity']
            yield item


    # Number of goods
    def __len__(self):
        return sum(item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())

    def get_total_price(self):
        return sum(Decimal(item['sale_price']) * item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())

    def clear(self):
        del self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID]
        self.session.modified = True

    #@property
    #def cupon(self):
     #   if self.cupon_id:
      #      return Cupon.objects.get(id=self.cupon_id)
       # return None

    #def get_discount(self):
     #   if self.cupon:
      #      return (self.cupon.discount / Decimal('100')) * self.get_total_price()
       # return Decimal('0')

    def get_total_price_after_discount(self):
        return self.get_total_price()
        #return self.get_total_price() - self.get_discount()
```

Below is the urls:

```
 path(r'^add/(?P<uid>\d+)/$', views.CartAdd, name='CartAdd'),
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to save it like this then the product will be added

```
cart(product=product, quantity=cd['quantity'], update_quantity=cd['update']).save()
```

There is a quicker method though:

Instead of saying `cart = Cart(request)`

you can say something like this:

```
Cart(product=product, quantity=cd['quantity'], update_quantity=cd['update']).save()
```

here use directly Cart model to save changes!

Comment: now my views will be like this or what:`@login_required
@require_POST
def CartAdd(request, uid):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(AffProduct, uid=uid)
    form = CartAddProductForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        cart(product=product, quantity=cd['quantity'], update_quantity=cd['update']).save()
    return redirect('CartDetail')`

Comment: Sorry for the tag, but i didnot get what u said. I have tried as u said , still products are not being added.

Comment: i mean to say, Cart is a model right? u added cart=Cart(request) instead of this u can directly call the Cart model: Cart(user=user).save()

Comment: For the product to be added make sure that you are getting the product. you can check it by print(product). if u get it then the problem is in the cart logic & if you don't get the product the problem is in the product logic. Try debugging it!

Comment: I am still trying
I am using cart.Cart(request), where cart is the file name and Cart is the class object where the functions , add , remove is defined

Comment: You can see it in cart.py